# how to make a script (PHP) that login to a site (No API) and clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, php, automation

I want to create a script that logins to a site , clicks a buttons and that's it.

I only need vocabulary (keywords) to search on google , because I'm really lost.

if you're nice , make an example !
thank you.

Comment: depends on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basic HTTP Authentication, HTTP Authentication with PHP, php requires and includes, secure login script php, user authentication php, php simple login script, login authentication with sql and php.

Here's a few helpful sites:

http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/05/adding-a-simple-authentication-using-php-require-and-includes/

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

http://blackbe.lt/php-secure-sessions/

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch08_10.htm

Answer (score 0):

first create a connection as like connection string with database 
**$email=cleanstr($_POST['email']);
    $pwd=cleanstr($_POST['password']);**
using these two variables to and for login system 
email id and password

```
<?php
require_once("connection.php"); // require the db connection
function cleanstr($str){
    $cstr=trim($str);
    $cstr=htmlspecialchars($cstr);
    $cstr=addslashes($cstr);
    return $cstr;
}
$email=cleanstr($_POST['email']);
$pwd=cleanstr($_POST['password']);

if(empty($email) && empty($pwd)){

        header("location:index.php");

    }
   else
{
$email=cleanstr($_POST['email']);
$pwd=cleanstr($_POST['password']);

  $search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."' AND password='".$pwd."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);
    if($match>0)
    {
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['email']= $email;
 // log in declare to the other page
 $_SESSION['login']=True;


header("Location:index.php");
    }
    else
    {

     echo "<script>
        window.alert ('Email or Password not match');
        window.location.href='login.php';
        </script>"; 

    }
// end of if
} 
?>
```